# Java instanciation syntax explanation

Tags: java, syntax, double-brace-initialize

Reading a Java project on GitHub, I found a code syntax that I have never seen before and I would some explanation, please. Here is the code:

```
Book book = new BookBuilder() {
    {
        description("blabla");
        author("blabla");
        title("blabla");
        isbn("123456789");
        category(category);
    }
}.build();
```

`BookBuilder` seems to be a standard java class and each of methods called (description, author...) return a `BookBuilder` object.
My question is, what does the syntax `book = new BookBuilder() {{ ... }}` means?

Comment: Is this project supposed to be written in Java 8?

Comment: Someone seems to have misunderstood the builder pattern.. It's meant to be `new BookBuilder().description("blabla").title("...).build()` without any braces.

Comment: try to read this http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/inner-classes/double-brace-initialization-in-java/

Comment: @marios89 apparently not, the pom is defined with _maven-compiler-plugin_ to 1.7

Comment: @Nogi, thx for your comment, I will read this article soon.

Comment: @zapl, thx, I will look for more information about this design pattern